# How to free an allocated memory without losing its value

Tags: c, valgrind, free

Hello I wrote this function in C that takes a string of words and returns a two dimensional char array with each case initialized to a word in the right order, I compiled and it did the assigned task

```
char **decompose_string(char *string)
{
int i,j=0;
char* temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));
char **words_array=malloc((string_words_number(string)+1)*sizeof(char*)); //string_words_number return the number of words in string string
for(i=0;i<string_words_number(string);i++)
{   

    temp=NULL;
    int l=0;
    while(string[j]!=' ' && *string)
    {   
        temp=realloc(temp,(l+1)*sizeof(char));
        temp[l]=string[j];
        j++;l++;
    }
    j++;
    temp[l]='\0';
    tab_mots=realloc(words_array,(string_words_number(string)+1)*sizeof(char)*(j-1));
    words_array[i]=temp;

}
words_array[i]=NULL;
return words_array;}
```

And my main:

```
int main()
{
char* string1= "word1 and word2 and word3";
printf("Our initial string: %s\n",string1);
char** words_array1;
printf("After decomposition:\n");
words_array1=decompose_string(string1);
display_words_array(words_array1); //displays each element of the array in a line
words_array1=destroy_array(words_array1);
return 0;}
```

But as I executed the valgrind command to see weither there are any memory leaks this was the result:

```
==4648== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4648== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4648== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4648== Command: ./test_csvl
==4648== 

Our initial array: word1 and word2 and word3
After decomposition:
==4648== Invalid write of size 1
==4648==    at 0x4009D9: decompose_string (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==    by 0x40078F: main (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==  Address 0x5204634 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4648==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4648==    by 0x40097D: decompose_string (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==    by 0x40078F: main (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648== 
==4648== Invalid read of size 1
==4648==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4648==    by 0x4EA969B: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==4648==    by 0x400888: display_words_array (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==    by 0x40079F: main (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==  Address 0x5204634 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4648==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4648==    by 0x40097D: decompose_string (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648==    by 0x40078F: main (in /home/omaima/2I001/TME3/test_csvl)
==4648== 
word1
and
word2
and
word3
==4648== 
==4648== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4648==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==4648==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 29 frees, 1,545 bytes allocated
==4648== 
==4648== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4648==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==4648==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4648==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4648==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4648==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4648== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4648== 
==4648== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4648== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I know that the missing free is the one for temp in the function but if I do free it I'll end up losing its value which I need for my array. So my question would be can I free it without losing its value ? or any other solution to guarantee both the functionality of my function and the erase of any memory leaks. Thank you for your time.

Sorry I forgot here's the function I used to free the allocated space:

```
char **destroy_words_array( char** words_array)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count_words(words_array);i++) free(words_array[i]); //wount_words return the number of elements of the array
    free(words_array);
    return words_array;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't free and not to loose a value. If you don't want to loose it, copy it before freeing.

Comment: It is an error to access any memory after you have `free`d it. Perhaps the best solution is for the code that uses the data to take responsibility for freeing it.

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, you don't use the value after you've free'ed it.  So why return it?

Comment: So basically you want to set your house on fire and continue to live in it once it has burned down?

Comment: The leak is not the issue with your code, but this here is `Invalid write of size 1` and this `Invalid read of size 1`.

Comment: `char* temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));` makes no sense whatsoever. Fortunately it only leaks memory and does nothing else destructive. In addition please use English identifiers in your programs if you want international audience to understand them.

Comment: `temp[l]='\0';` what is `l` at this point? What was the length argument in the last call to `realloc`?

Comment: @alk how can I fix that, please ?

Comment: @dbush when I do free temp I end up with losing the last value of the array and a segmentation fault

Comment: @n.m. what would make more sense please ? I will edit it right away sorry.

Comment: @OmaimaRaddi Leaking memory by itself won't cause a segfault.  Reading/writing past the end of allocated memory (as reported) will.  You've already been given a hint as to where it is.

Comment: I'd say 1st compile with symbols (GCC option `-g`) then rerun Valgrind, and it'll point you to the critical source lines.

Comment: @n.m. l is the length of each word I pass to the array that's why I keep initializing to fit each word

Comment: It would be easier if you operate with specific numbers. Note I asked you to look at *two* numbers, not one.

Comment: The english language bit is for the future, don't do massive edits on existing programs hastily.

Comment: @n.m. it was l+1 because I use realloc before incrementing l's value, for the '\0' at the end of a string

Comment: Please give two **specific** numbers. Don't guess, add a `printf` or use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory leak isn't where you think it is.  It happens at the start of your function:

```
char* temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));
char **words_array=malloc((string_words_number(string)+1)*sizeof(char*)); 
for(i=0;i<string_words_number(string);i++)
{   

    temp=NULL;
```

You allocate space for a pointer to `temp`, but then you overwrite that pointer when  you enter the `for` loop.  Remove that `malloc` call and the leak goes away.

You have a bigger problem however, and that is reading and writing past the end of an allocated buffer.  That's happening here:

```
temp=NULL;
int l=0;
while(string[j]!=' ' && *string)
{   
    temp=realloc(temp,(l+1)*sizeof(char));
    temp[l]=string[j];
    j++;l++;
}
j++;
temp[l]='\0';
```

Suppose the string in question has two characters to read.  On the first iteration of your loop, `l` is 0, so you allocate `l+1 == 1` bytes to `temp`.  You then write to `temp[l] == temp[0]`, which is fine, then you increment `l` to 1.  On the next iteration, you allocate `l+1 == 2` bytes for `temp`, write to `temp[l] == temp[1]`, and increment `l` to 2.  Still good so far.

The problem is when you do `temp[l]='\0';` outside of the loop.  `l` is now 2, and the size of the allocated memory is 2, so you're writing one element past the end of the array.

You need to allocate one more byte here:

```
j++;
temp=realloc(temp,(l+1)*sizeof(char));
temp[l]='\0';
```

Note also that you should be checking the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` throughout your code in case it fails.

Also, you're not correctly checking for the end of `string`.  You need to do:

```
while(string[j]!=' ' && string[j]!=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the for-loop you have

```
char* temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

but the first thing inside the for-loop is

```
temp=NULL;
```

So the memory that `temp` pointed to is lost. If you run this program on a 64 bit computer, you will see a memory leak of size 8. Remove the first declaration of `temp` and change the first line in the for-loop to

```
char* temp = NULL;
```

Another problem is the condition of the inner while-loop:

```
while(chaine[j]!=' ' && *chaine)
```

as you don't advance the `chaine` pointer, the value of `*chaine` will not change. You probably meant to write `chaine[j]` here:

```
while(chaine[j]!=' ' && chaine[j])
```

which is equivalent to

```
while(chaine[j]!=' ' && chaine[j]!='\0')
```